# VBA ClickBot featuring AJAX waiting and Element searching

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

If you work with a database that you only have access through a web interface, this one is for you.  You probably don't have access to any programming languages other than VBA through MS Office, which I 95% guarantee you do have.

Since we will be controlling an external instance of Internet Explorer, you will need to reference `Mircosoft Internet Controls` for this to work.  One could hack this to work with Firefox or Chrome with extensions like Selenium.

### Usage

This is meant to be placed in an add-in so we can create an instance from the pseudo-constructors.

```
Dim navi As Gator
Set navi = Gator.Home("https://www.google.com/", php:=False)
```

Navigating to a url will raise an error if the browser doesn't navigate to the requested URL. The `php:=False` option ignores trailing `php` code added.  You can also grab an existing instance of IE using the window title.

```
Set navi = Gator.FromWindow("Google")
```

It's nifty if you don't want to re-login to a database or catch a popup window.

There are currently two ways to access HTML elements on the page.

1. By id or name
2. Using `HtmlFields` object

By id is the recommended method if available.  You find the `id` or `name` of the element and use

```
With Gator.Home("http://codereview.stackexchange.com/")
    .GetElByID("nav-questions").Click
End With
```

If the element does not have an ID you can specify the tag of the element and any other properties of the sought element

```
With Gator.Home("http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69009/vba-clickbot-featuring-ajax-waiting-and-element-searching")
    .FindEl(HtmlFields.Make("a", innerText:="up vote", _
        title:="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear")).Click
    .FindEl(HtmlFields.Make("a", innerText:="add a comment")).Click
    .FindEl(HtmlFields.Make("textarea")).value = "WOW! This is super neat!"
    .FindEl(HtmlFields.Make("input", value:="Add Comment")).Click
End With
```

**I highly recommend you give that a try**

Notice that we aren't required to wait for pages or elements to load.  That is the primary purpose of `Gator`.  It will attempt to access the element until it is found or it times out and raises an error.  Both methods have an optional `timeOut` parameter which is default 5 seconds.

Because of the brute force waiting, the code is extremely inefficient.  `FindEl` will perform a linear search on all elements of the given tag name at least 3 times before a successful return.  I am looking for ways to reduce that.  Still, the inefficiency is negligible in comparison to IE's operations.

*Begin Code Dump*

---

## HtmlFields

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "HtmlFields"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit

' Private Members
' ---------------

''
' Dictionary of `property => result`
Private criteria As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set criteria = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

### Constructor

I would prefer to allow users to specify the property name of the element searching for instead of restricting them to the one's I have provided.  It would be more flexible for the client and less code for me.  However, I don't know how I should implement the association between the property and the expected value without inline dictionary definitions which could almost negate this class.

```
Public Function Make(ByVal tagName As String, _
        Optional ByVal className As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal value As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal innerText As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal innerHTML As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal typeName As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal title As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal href As String = "", _
        Optional ByVal style As String = "") As HtmlFields

    Set Make = New HtmlFields
    With Make

        If tagName = "" Then
            Err.Raise 720, "HtmlFields.Make", "tagName cannot be a null string"
        End If

        .Add "tagName", UCase(tagName)
        .Add "className", className
        .Add "value", value
        .Add "innerText", innerText
        .Add "innerHTML", innerHTML
        .Add "type", typeName
        .Add "title", title
        .Add "href", href
        .Add "style", style

    End With

End Function
```

### Friend Methods

Soley used for constructor

```
''
' If value is blank then the option wasn't provided.
Friend Sub Add(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)
    If value <> "" Then criteria.Add key, value
End Sub
Friend Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = criteria.Count
End Property
```

### Public Properties

```
Public Function GetTags(ByVal htmlDoc As Object) As Object
    Set GetTags = htmlDoc.getelementsbytagname(criteria("tagName"))
End Function
Public Function IsMatch(ByVal element As Object) As Boolean

    Dim pass As Boolean
    Dim field As Variant
    For Each field In criteria.Keys

        pass = (CallByName(element, field, VbGet) = criteria(field))
        If Not pass Then Exit For

    Next field

    IsMatch = pass

End Function
```

---

## Gator

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Gator"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit

' Required .dlls
' `Microsoft Internet Controls`
'
' # Members
' ## Private Members
Private pBrowser As Object

Enum GatorErrors
    wrong_location = 360
    failed_el_get
End Enum
```

### Public Browser Properties

```
Public Property Let Visible(ByVal state As Boolean)
    pBrowser.Visible = state
End Property
```

### Friend Properties

```
' For constructors
'
Friend Property Set Browser(ByRef other As InternetExplorer)
    Set pBrowser = other
End Property
Friend Property Get Browser() As InternetExplorer
    Set Browser = pBrowser
End Property
```

### Constructors

```
Public Function FromWindow(ByVal title As String) As Gator

    WaitFor "PopupExists", title, 30

    Dim navi As New Gator
    Set navi.Browser = GetWindowFromTitle(title)
    Set FromWindow = navi

End Function
Public Function Home(ByVal homeURL As String) As Gator

    Dim navi As New Gator
    navi.UrlGo homeURL
    Set Home = navi

End Function
```

### Navigation

```
Public Sub UrlGo(ByVal destination As String, Optional php As Boolean = False)

    If pBrowser Is Nothing Then Set pBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    pBrowser.Visible = True

    pBrowser.navigate destination
    Wait

    Dim location As String
    If php Then
        location = pBrowser.LocationURL
    Else
        location = Split(pBrowser.LocationURL, "?")(0)
    End If

    If location <> destination Then
        pBrowser.Visible = True
        Err.Raise GatorErrors.wrong_location, "UrlGo", _
            "Hey! Listen! Browser didn't navigate to: " & destination
    End If

End Sub
```

### Public Routines

```
Public Sub Quit()
    pBrowser.Quit
End Sub
Public Sub Wait()

    While pBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or pBrowser.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

End Sub
Public Sub WaitFor(ByVal existsName As String, ByVal arg0 As Variant, _
        ByVal timeOut As Integer)

    Dim start As Single
    start = timer
    Do Until CallByName(Me, existsName, VbMethod, arg0) _
    Or start + timeOut < timer
        DoEvents
    Loop
    If Not CallByName(Me, existsName, VbMethod, arg0) Then
        pBrowser.Visible = True
        Err.Raise GatorErrors.failed_el_get, "WaitFor", _
            "Hey!, Listen! " & existsName & " failed to find requested element"
    End If
End Sub
```

### Public Accessors

```
' ### byID
'
' The best way to do it by far.  If the website is properly built and every
' element has some kind of ID then this is the way to go.
' You can wait for elements to exist if you know the ID
Public Function GetElByID(ByVal id As String, Optional ByVal timeOut As Long = 5) As Object

    WaitFor "IdExists", id, timeOut
    Set GetElByID = pBrowser.document.getelementbyID(id)

End Function
Public Function IdExists(ByVal id As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim el As Object
    Set el = pBrowser.document.getelementbyID(id)
    IdExists = Not (el Is Nothing)

End Function
'
' ### By Filter
'
Public Function FindEl(ByVal fields As HtmlFields, Optional ByVal timeOut As Long = 5) As Object

    WaitFor "CanFindElement", fields, timeOut
    Set FindEl = FieldSearch(fields)

End Function
Public Function CanFindElement(ByVal fields As HtmlFields) As Boolean

    CanFindElement = Not (FieldSearch(fields) Is Nothing)

End Function

### Popup

Public Function PopupExists(ByVal title As String) As Boolean
    PopupExists = Not (GetWindowFromTitle(title) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

### Private Accessors

```
Private Function GetDoc() As Object

    Wait
    Set GetDoc = pBrowser.document

End Function
Private Function FieldSearch(ByRef fields As HtmlFields) As Object

    Dim element As Object
    For Each element In fields.GetTags(GetDoc)

        If fields.IsMatch(element) Then

            Set FieldSearch = element
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next element

End Function
```

#### Popup Catching

```
''
' heavily refactored from StackExchange
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba
' You will need to reference `Microsoft Internet Controls`
Private Function GetWindowFromTitle(ByVal sTitle As String, _
        Optional ByVal bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
        Optional ByVal bExact As Boolean = False) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    Dim window As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    For Each window In objShellWindows
        If hasWindowTitle(window, sTitle, bCaseSensitive, bExact) Then
            Set GetWindowFromTitle = window
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Set GetWindowFromTitle = Nothing

End Function
Private Function hasWindowTitle(win As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, ByVal title As String, _
       ByVal bCaseSensitive As Boolean, ByVal bExact As Boolean) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Nope

    Dim pass As Boolean
    pass = (typeName(win.document) = "HTMLDocument")

    If Not pass Then GoTo CleanExit

    Dim docTitle As String
    docTitle = win.document.title

    If Not bCaseSensitive Then
        docTitle = LCase(docTitle)
        title = LCase(title)
    End If

    If bExact Then
        pass = (docTitle = title)
    Else
        pass = InStr(1, docTitle, title) <> 0
    End If

CleanExit:
    hasWindowTitle = pass
Exit Function
Nope:
    pass = False
    Resume CleanExit

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to say that this is pretty damn impressive. Really. I'm not going to go through this line by line; my general impression is that it looks pretty readable, procedures are of decent length, it's clear what's going on.

I wonder why the late binding here:

```
Private criteria As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set criteria = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

With a reference to the `Scripting` library, it could look like this:

```
Private criteria As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

And nothing in the `Initialize` handler. But this whole binding point is moot, I'll get back to why.

There's this `Make` function:

```
Public Function Make(...)
```

The function is being assigned a new instance of `HtmlFields`, *and then* that instance is being modified:

```
Set Make = New HtmlFields
With Make

    If tagName = "" Then
        Err.Raise 720, "HtmlFields.Make", "tagName cannot be a null string"
    End If

    .Add "tagName", UCase(tagName)
    .Add "className", className
    .Add "value", value
    .Add "innerText", innerText
    .Add "innerHTML", innerHTML
    .Add "type", typeName
    .Add "title", title
    .Add "href", href
    .Add "style", style

End With
```

I like the usage you've made of the `With` statement, but not how you're using the function's handle as a simple object variable; you and I *know* that it *can* be used like that, but it's always better not to. I'd much rather like to see this:

```
Set result = New HtmlFields
With result

    If tagName = "" Then
        Err.Raise 720, "HtmlFields.Make", "tagName cannot be a null string"
    End If

    .Add "tagName", UCase(tagName)
    .Add "className", className
    .Add "value", value
    .Add "innerText", innerText
    .Add "innerHTML", innerHTML
    .Add "type", typeName
    .Add "title", title
    .Add "href", href
    .Add "style", style

End With

Set Make = result
```

It's not *only* a matter of personal preference: treating the function's identifier as a variable can lead to unexpected issues if you're not careful, and almost always creates a little surprise to the reader.

> *I would prefer to allow users to specify the property name of the element searching for instead of restricting them to the one's I have provided.*

Oh yeah. Ok. Ready for a little bit of [oop](/questions/tagged/oop)?

```
Attribute VB_Name = "HtmlField"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit

Private Type THtmlField
    FieldName As String
    FieldValue As String
End Type

Private this As THtmlField

Public Function Make(ByVal field As String, ByVal value As String) As HtmlField

    Dim result As New HtmlField
    result.FieldName = field
    result.FieldValue = value

    Set Make = result

End Function

'default property:
Public Property Get FieldName() As String
    Attribute FieldName.VB_UserMemId = 0
    FieldName = this.FieldName
End Property

Friend Property Let FieldName(ByVal value As String)
    If value = vbNullString Then
        Err.Raise 720, "HtmlField.FieldName (Property Let)", "Invalid argument: [value] cannot be set to an empty string."
    End If
    this.FieldName = value
End Property

Public Property Get FieldValue As String
    FieldValue = this.FieldValue
End Property

Friend Property Let FieldValue(ByVal value As String)
    this.FieldValue = value
End Property
```

So we have this sort-of-public-interface-immutable type with a default instance, that encapsulates its own validation rule(s). With the first recommended modification, this means we can now remove all these optional parameters and have the `Make` function look like this:

```
Public Function Make(ByVal tagName As String, ) As HtmlFields

    Set Make = New HtmlFields
    With Make

        If tagName = "" Then
            Err.Raise 720, "HtmlFields.Make", "tagName cannot be a null string"
        End If

        .Add "tagName", UCase(tagName)
        .Add "className", className
        .Add "value", value
        .Add "innerText", innerText
        .Add "innerHTML", innerHTML
        .Add "type", typeName
        .Add "title", title
        .Add "href", href
        .Add "style", style

    End With

End Function
```

And now we don't need this anymore, because *value is never going to be blank*:

```
''
' If value is blank then the option wasn't provided.
Friend Sub Add(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)
    If value <> "" Then criteria.Add key, value
End Sub
```

Actually, the `HtmlField` abstraction implements the key/value concept; there's no need to use a `Scripting.Dictionary` anymore, because instead of this:

```
Public Function IsMatch(ByVal element As Object) As Boolean

    Dim pass As Boolean
    Dim field As Variant
    For Each field In criteria.Keys

        pass = (CallByName(element, field, VbGet) = criteria(field))
        If Not pass Then Exit For

    Next field

    IsMatch = pass

End Function
```

We could have that:

```
Public Function IsMatch(ByVal element As Object) As Boolean

    Dim pass As Boolean
    Dim condition As HtmlField
    For Each condition In criteria

        pass = (CallByName(element, condition.FieldName, VbGet) = condition.FieldValue)
        If Not pass Then Exit For

    Next

    IsMatch = pass

End Function
```

And then `criteria` can be a simple everyday `Collection` instance, and whether you late-bind or reference the `Scripting` library is moot as promised.

Comment: Can you provide an example usage of the new structure?  My understanding is that `HtmlFeilds` would now have an `ParamArray` constructor that accepts `HtmlField` objects.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the other answer didn't touch the `Gator` class, so I'll focus on that.

---

> ```
> ' Required .dlls
> ' `Microsoft Internet Controls`
> ```

Well done right there. All too often there is no documentation about what references a piece of code needs to work. Someone will thank you for that someday without a doubt.

> ```
> Public Property Let Visible(ByVal state As Boolean)
>     pBrowser.Visible = state
> End Property
> ```

There's nothing wrong with this code, but it might be nice to expose a getter too. That way the client code could take action based on whether or not the browser is visible. There is such a thing as too much symmetry, but I definitely don't see any harm in exposing it. It always feels a little weird when you can set a property, but not inspect it.

> ```
> ' For constructors
> '
> Friend Property Set Browser(ByRef other As InternetExplorer)
>     Set pBrowser = other
> End Property
> Friend Property Get Browser() As InternetExplorer
>     Set Browser = pBrowser
> End Property
>
> Public Function FromWindow(ByVal title As String) As Gator
>
>     WaitFor "PopupExists", title, 30
>
>     Dim navi As New Gator
>     Set navi.Browser = GetWindowFromTitle(title)
>     Set FromWindow = navi
>
> End Function
> Public Function Home(ByVal homeURL As String) As Gator
>
>     Dim navi As New Gator
>     navi.UrlGo homeURL
>     Set Home = navi
>
> End Function
> ```

I find this to be a beautiful use of the underutilized `Friend` scope. You wouldn't want to expose the property outside of the project, and you don't. Fantastic!

> ```
>   location = Split(pBrowser.LocationURL, "?")(0)
> ```

That is smart and clean way to get a substring, but has potential to confuse a rookie. Consider adding a comment.

> ```
> Public Sub Wait()
>
>     While pBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or pBrowser.Busy
>         DoEvents
>     Wend
>
> End Sub
> ```

This is really picky, but I'd like to see a set of parenthesis here. It just clears up the intent.

```
While (pBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE) Or pBrowser.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
```

> ```
> Public Sub WaitFor(ByVal existsName As String, ByVal arg0 As Variant, _
>         ByVal timeOut As Integer)
>
>     Dim start As Single
>     start = timer
>     Do Until CallByName(Me, existsName, VbMethod, arg0) _
>     Or start + timeOut < timer
>         DoEvents
>     Loop
>     If Not CallByName(Me, existsName, VbMethod, arg0) Then
>         pBrowser.Visible = True
>         Err.Raise GatorErrors.failed_el_get, "WaitFor", _
>             "Hey!, Listen! " & existsName & " failed to find requested element"
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

`arg0` is a variant here because you need to pass an `HTMLFields` object to it in one place. Again, consider a comment explaining why you declared it as a variant. Also, I don't much like the name `arg0`, but I'm drawing a blank on something better at the moment.

The other thing I'm seeing here is that you raise the same error if the element is not found as you do if it simply times out. I would raise two different errors depending on the situation if you can. It makes for a friendlier API to do so.

> ```
> Public Function IdExists(ByVal id As String) As Boolean
>
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Dim el As Object
>     Set el = pBrowser.document.getelementbyID(id)
>     IdExists = Not (el Is Nothing)
>
> End Function
> ```

You're a good programmer, so I won't question that you need to use `On Error Resume Next` here, but you *definitely* should add a comment here explaining why you're doing it. As it is, I don't have to domain knowledge to understand why you're doing this (and neither will the person maintaining the code someday).

> ```
> Private Function GetDoc() As Object
>
>     Wait
>     Set GetDoc = pBrowser.document
>
> End Function
> Private Function FieldSearch(ByRef fields As HtmlFields) As Object
>
>     Dim element As Object
>     For Each element In fields.GetTags(GetDoc)
>
>         If fields.IsMatch(element) Then
>
>             Set FieldSearch = element
>             Exit Function
>
>         End If
>
>     Next element
>
> End Function
> ```

You're already aware that this is a linear and slow search method, but as you pointed out, it shouldn't affect overall performance much. What I wanted to mention is that there's a lot of `Object` here. You're already referencing the library, so you should go ahead and strongly type these if you can.

> ```
> ' heavily refactored from StackExchange
> ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba
> ' You will need to reference `Microsoft Internet Controls`
> Private Function GetWindowFromTitle(ByVal sTitle As String, _
>         Optional ByVal bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
>         Optional ByVal bExact As Boolean = False) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
>
>     Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
>
>     Dim window As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
>     For Each window In objShellWindows
>         If hasWindowTitle(window, sTitle, bCaseSensitive, bExact) Then
>             Set GetWindowFromTitle = window
>             Exit Function
>         End If
>     Next
>     Set GetWindowFromTitle = Nothing
>
> End Function
> ```

Thanks for the proper attribution!, but OP's hungarian is showing. Burn it. It mars your otherwise beautiful naming.

---

That's all I've got. This is pretty darn impeccable looking code as far as I see. Pretty cool project too in my opinion.

Comment: `IdExists` should say `On Error GoTo 0` immediately after the line that expects the error, to restore error handling. Otherwise it *may* be hiding problems, because `On Error Resume Next` turns off error handling altogether, even beyond the procedure's scope (until another `On Error` statement is encountered).

Comment: @Mat'sMug I might just use `On Error GoTo Nope` as I usually do.  It's more lines but it will be self documenting.

Comment: @ptwales [nevermind](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18597687#18597687)